# Selenium 3.0.1 geckodriver v.011.1 Firefox 49.0.2 not sending values to input fields

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium3

Setup:

- Firefox 49.0.2
- Geckodriver v.011.1
- Selenium 3.0.1

I have problems with some input fields that is using ractive. The value is not set. I'm able to see the value been sent to the input field in Firefox, but when hitting the "Save" button no value is set.

I've tried this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#at-OrganizationUnitEditTextInputName_Name').focus()")
driver.execute_script("return document.activeElement") # This returns the the correct element
```

and then

```
element.clear()
time.sleep(0.2)
element.send_keys(keys)
```

This problem occured after upgrading to Selenium 3.0.1 and geckodriver. There was no problem when using the old firefox driver. I used this in the old driver to set focus before sending keys:

```
element.send_keys(Keys.NULL) # Set focus
time.sleep(0.2)
element.clear()
time.sleep(0.2)
element.send_keys(keys)
```

Neither the 'focusin' or 'blur' events were fired in the javascript. Seems like this it's the blur event ractive use when setting values?

I've also tried the ActionChains and move_to_element, but it's not possible due to an exception:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: POST /session/325f067c-755d-4401-9c42-4219def280eb/moveto did not match a known command

**Update**:
I tested with Chrome driver and was able to send keys to the input fields. So I guess it's an issue with the geckodriver